# Why are there two buttons that link to /unanswered and /questions?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

In the /questions page, there are 2 buttons that link to /unanswered:

[image]

And in the /unanswered page, there are 2 buttons that link to /questions:

[image]

Apparently, this does not happen on MSE:

[image]

On MSE, there isn't even an /unanswered page!

Why is it designed like so? Can't SO be like MSE? The blue buttons are kind of unnecessary. This can reduce some white space.

Comment: It did confuse me when I saw the "Answer questions" link. We should know where to go to answer questions, either the "newest" or "unanswered" ones

Comment: When looking at questions for a tag the "all questions" point at different locations. Left to "all questions" and right to "all questions for tag X".

Comment: @André That's interesting, but doesn't make it better at all. Having 2 buttons with the same text on the same page perform different actions is bad UI, and can make written instructions confusing.

Comment: This is a bug. We will look into it.

Comment: Similarily there are links to "Info" and "Learn more..." linking to the same page on Public questions tagged [ ] pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short... as part of working of Teams, we made a number of UI and layout changes that were shown to Teams users but not anyone else. At the same time, the design team has been working on updating and streamlining our site layouts. Along the way, the styles that were done for Stack Overflow (and Teams) became a base for the "unified" design we're in the process of testing and rolling out network-wide.

So, a check that used to be "if current user sees Teams" became "if current user sees Teams OR unified theme is enabled". Fine, no problem. Except that further down, we also have a site setting check that decides whether to show those blue links or regular tabs. That check now also needs to only apply to Teams users, and that bit was missing.

I wrangled boolean logic back in place, so we shouldn't be doubling on the display.