# Where are the unanswered questions?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, left-navigation

I remember that there used to be a list of unanswered questions and I think even one of new questions, but now I can’t find them.

[image]

I just feel, starting today, I am missing information that used to be on the top of the page and the bar by the side takes up space from the questions/answers.

Comment: They've been moved to [Sweeper](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369440/7296893). Since he has 2 links, there unfortunately were none left for you.

Comment: (but in all seriousness, apparently that link is not available on the front page, but available twice on the [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth lol that's kinda funny, one page has too many, and one is too short.

Comment: Actually I don't remember the "unanswered"  button being in the homepage even before the new design. It has always been located in /questions.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth What do you mean by twice on the questions page?

Comment: Exactly, it has always been under `/questions`

Comment: @Catija See the link from my first comment. That explains it.

Comment: I answered them all yesterday, so the tab is gone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is not an option on the "Home" tab.  Click the "Stack Overflow" selection from the left navigation, and the unanswered option appears:

[image: Location of unanswered tab]

Comment: Oh that's confusing, I thought "Stack Overflow" and Home (while standing in the SO landing page) were the same.

Comment: Agreed that it's confusing, between the (lack of) sidebar scrolling that's brought up in [the announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness), and unanswered posts getting tucked away here, this whole design update is a usability nightmare :/

Comment: I noticed this yesterday. So why does the "Stack Overflow" menu item go to `/questions` Is that what people expect when they click on that menu item?? Why doesn't 'Home' look the same? Or at least have the same buttons? I would totally expect "Home" and the "Stack Overflow" items to go to the same place. Which would be kind of redundant in itself, but that would be my expectation.

Comment: I'm doubly confused by this. If I click on Stack Overflow under PUBLIC I go to `/questions` and I have only 3 buttons on that page: "newest", "active" and "more". Under "more" I have "bounties", "votes" and "frequent". There is no "unanswered" button unless I hack the URL to `/unanswered`. I am a member of 2 teams; I have cleared my brower cache; and I have a number of user scripts active on SO but the issue remains with Tampermonkey disabled.