# " Answer questions"? all of them at the same time?

Tags: discussion, support, design

Yes again another question about the new layout and about a link I don't understand *(maybe it was there before but I never notice it)*

[image]

What is the purpose of the "answer questions" link. I discovered it's linked to the unanswered questions but the link is already there is the same page and it's more clear.

The label is a bit confusing. It's clear that **Ask Question** is to ask a question but **Answer questions** isn't to answer all the questions. It will simply take you to the unanswered questions but we can also answer answered questions. So why adding this link there?

**UPDATE**

When we have few questions (like in the featured tab) and due to the responsive feature we will have this view:

[image]

And without this *strange* link we will have a cleaner header:

[image]

Comment: Clicking the "Answer Questions" button adds an auto-reply style answer that says "42" to all questions. I don't recommend you push it.

Comment: @DavyM too late already did it :/ ... on my way to get back to 1Rep ... ah got accepted for a question asking "what is the result of 40+2" :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif Pfft. The only valid answer to "what is the result of 40+2" is that you can [calculate it using the jQuery basic arithmetic plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

Comment: Ahh but that begs the question: what _is_ the meaning of life, the universe, and everything?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369440/7296893): apparently there are changes to be made to this button anyway.

Comment: @TinyGiant Please stop using "beg the question" to mean ["raise the question."](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/begs-the-question) ;)

Comment: @Draco18s I did not mean "raise the question", I meant "begs the question".